# New Install Keyboard and Mouse not Responding on Login

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Elementary OS 0.4 Loki on my PC and the install went fine, but after I restarted my mouse and keyboard did not respond when I landed at the login screen so I'm stuck. I changed over to my Windows 10 install and both the mouse and keyboard work fine there. I also tried booting into recovery mode and my keyboard didn't work there either.

Comment: Do the keyboard and mouse work on the Live USB? I assume so as you installed successfully.

Answer (score -1):

you can install elementary OS once again